# How can I flip n number of bits in a number in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

How can I flip "n" number of lower/higher bits in a number using the xor operation in assembly?

How would the mask be calculated? For example, if n=2 for "1110" the mask would be "1100" for higher 2 and "0011" for lower two, however for "111111" it would be "110000" for higher two, and "000011" for lower two. So what is the correlation between n=2 and those masks? How can I create them just based on the number of bits that need to be flipped and not based on the actual number that's being flipped? (supposing that we don't know the number beforehand) Thank you in advance!

I tried finding the number of bits the number I am working with has, and I believe have managed to do so but still can't find the correlation.

Comment: Did you have any specific architecture in mind, like x86 where `bsf` and `bsr` are available to find the position of the lowest or highest set bit in a fixed-width register?  Normally we talk about fixed-width integers, e.g. an 8-bit register, where the mask for the highest 2 bits would always be `11000000`.  But it seems you mean 2 bits counting down from the highest *set* bit in the value, not the top bit of a register?  But for the low bit you are talking about the edge of the register, not the lowest set bit?

Comment: What happens if the input number is `00000000`, but you want to flip the 2 highest bits?  Do you leave it unchanged, flip the low 2 bits, the high 2 bits, or what?

Comment: Constructing masks for the low 2 bits is `(1<<n) - 1`, but without overflow if you want to be able to support n=32 to flip all 32 bits in a 32-bit register for example.  On x86 with BMI2, you can do this with `bzhi` on an all-ones bit-pattern. Like `mov edx, -1` / `bzhi  edx, edx, ecx` / `xor eax, edx`, where ecx=n.  e.g. if ECX=2, then it will keep the low 2 bits set, clearing everything above that to make a `0b00...0011` mask.

Comment: @peter sorry for not being more clear, yes x86. I was looking at a  32-bit register however on your example of a 8-bit register, if the number was 11110000 your mask would work, but if it was a smaller number (sorry If I am not using the right terminology) for example 1111 ( 00001111 in the register) that mask wouldn't work because the number is not represented by all 8bits ?

Comment: For the high bits, maybe isolate the highest set bit and subtract something from it?

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by (1<<n) - 1? oh! Shifting 1, okay! Sorry

Comment: Flipping the high 2 bits of the register or flipping the 2 most-significant bits of the value are two different things, either of them potentially useful in different cases.  You should [edit] your question with clear terminology, or just examples that have some `0` bits to the left of the `1`, to make it clear you're still wanting your set bits to line up with the top set bit in the value, regardless of the register width.  I figured that's what you wanted, but it seemed odd that leading zeros never got mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that given the number of bits in the number you can determine what the mask you should be by using bit shift operations. For example, if you want to flip the lowest n bits you could do something like

```
mask = (1 << n) - 1;
value = value ^ mask;
```

If you want to flip the highest n bits you would need to do something like

```
mask = ((1<<(n))-1) << (number of bits - n);
value = value ^ mask;
```

Comment: In assembly, you normally don't actually want a shift instruction, you want `xor eax,eax` / `bts eax, edx` if the count is in EDX.  (@StevieRoberts).  That's more efficient on Intel CPUs at least than `mov eax,1` / `shl eax, cl` (the shift alone is 3 uops on modern Intel; https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: Also, you forgot to mention the possibility of overflow, for example if `n=32` and you do this with a 32-bit register, on x86 `shl eax, 32` is the same as `shl eax, 0`; it wraps the count.  You could use `shl rax, 32` / `sub eax, 1` in 64-bit code.  Or use `bzhi` if you have BMI2.

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point I was mostly thinking about how to construct the masks from a mathematical perspective. I wasn't really thinking about it from the computer architect perspective. But if you need a fast implementation that stuff will matter and also accounting for overflow is an important consideration.